# How can I reference a JavaScript variable as a value in an expression with Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

new to mapbox and enjoying my journey so far.

I am curious if there is a way to reference a javascript variable within an expression.

I am trying to essentially reference some color values that are dynamic, However I've had no luck. I went through the MB docs but I havent been able to find information or options that match my conundrum. Thank you for any info, pointers.

```
const mbFillColorExpressionValue = Object.keys(fills)
   .map(fips => {
      return `"${fips}","${fills[fips].fill}"`;
   })
   .concat('"white"')
   .toString();

(mbFillColorExpressionValue returns a string "18089","#839EBE","18091","#839EBE","18127","#839EBE","white")


  this.map.setPaintProperty('counties-towns', 'fill-color', [
     'match',
     ['get', 'GEOID'],
     geoids,
     mbFillColorExpressionValue
   ]);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on  what you mean with *a way to reference a javascript variable within an expression*? According to the [docs on `setPaintProperty`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setpaintproperty) accepts three arguments, where the third is should be a hexadecimal color code instead of an array. What are you trying to build here?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier sure.

So I notice I can use an expression as the third argument in `setPaintProperty`, and if I hardcode the values in the 4th argument in the `match` expression it works....the problem is I dont know what those colors will be.

So basically 

  this.map.setPaintProperty('counties-towns', 'fill-color', [
     'match',
     ['get', 'GEOID'],
     geoids,
     "18089","#839EBE","18091","#839EBE","18127","#839EBE","white"
   ]); 

Works...but I need to be able to reference those fips/color codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [docs of Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match), I think the end result should look something like the code below. Each `GEOID` is paired with its corresponding `fill`. And the color `white` as a fallback on the last line.

```
this.map.setPaintProperty('counties-towns', 'fill-color', [
  'match',
   ['get', 'GEOID'],
   '18089', '#839EBE',
   '18091', '#839EBE',
   '18127', '#839EBE',
   'white'
]);
```

To get to that result we first have to change the `map` method to a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). This is because we can't add any keys when mapping over an array, but we can return an array for each item and the flatten it to turn the whole thing into a single array.

```
const mbFillColorExpressionValue = Object.keys(fills).flatMap(fips => [fips, fills[fips].fill]);
mbFillColorExpressionValue.push('white');
```

From here we can use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) to place the contents of the `mbFillColorExpressionValue` array into the expression.

```
this.map.setPaintProperty('counties-towns', 'fill-color', [
  'match',
   ['get', 'GEOID'],
   ...mbFillColorExpressionValue
]);
```

Comment: Yup....ahhh ok. I was pretty close on the idea but yeh, I didnt realize a string variable would not be interrupted by the expression in the argument,  "figuring out the correct mappings". Thank you for the answer, saved me from the head to wall banging moment haha